# angular.js: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, mean-stack

I keep getting this error and I cannot figure it why:

```
angular.js:13708 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: fstackProvider <- fstack <- MainController
```

Here is a config.js file:

```
angular.module("app")
.constant("fstack", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
```

Here is my app.js file:

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('app', ['addCarCtrl', 'galleryCtrl','detailCtrl', 'userCtrl', 'ngRoute', 'angular-filepicker'])
  app.controller('MainController', MainController);
  function MainController($scope, fstack) {
    $scope.fstack = fstack;
  }
  app.config(function($routeProvider, filepickerProvider){
      //The route provider handles the client request to switch route
      $routeProvider.when('/addCar', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/addCar.html',
          controller: 'addCarController'
      })
      .when('/gallery', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/gallery.html',
          controller: 'galleryController'
      })
      .when('/detail/:id', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/detail.html',
          controller: 'detailController'
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'userController'
      })
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
      })
      //Redirect to addCar in all the other cases.
      .otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

      filepickerProvider.setKey('{{fstack}}');
 });
})();
```

Here is some of my HTML file:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AMC MEAN app</a>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/#/addCar">Add Car</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="/#/gallery">Gallery</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- Here is where the partials will be displayed -->
<div ng-view ng-controller="MainController"></div>
```

When I add the ng-controller="MainController" I get this error. I am trying to get access the $scope.fstack so I thought I should add the MainController in. It is obvious I do not know what I am doing but if anyone has any thoughts that could help me out that would be awesome. I need to get the value contained in the `$scope.fstack` to this set key.

```
 filepickerProvider.setKey('{{fstack}}');
```

Comment: See [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) article.

Comment: Try to add `.constant("fstack", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")` in `app.js` !

Comment: The xxxxxxxxxxxx is an api key that I do not want exposed in the browser. If I do that will the xxxxxxxxxxxx be available for people to get to in the browser?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to declare everything that you're injecting into the controller.

Try `app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', 'fstack', MainController]);`

Answer (score 0):

Define constant before controller.

```
angular.module("app")
    .constant("fstack", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

      app.controller('MainController', MainController);
      function MainController($scope, fstack) {
        $scope.fstack = fstack;
      }
```

Comment: If I do this will the xxxxxxxx be exposed to people in the browser? it is an api key. Thanks